# Looping through List and Returning Different Value based on Index Position

Tags: freemarker

Right now I have list by the name of listA
Within listA is listA[0] up to a max of listA[10] but the range varies.

All list entries in listA should have attribute 'name'

If listA[0].name = 'Apple Pie' then I would like to return 'First', however if listA[x].name = 'Apple Pie' only when x >= 1 then I would like to return 'Secondary/Non Primary'.

Is this possible to contain within a Freemarker expression to dynamically asses how long the list is and to return a different value based on whether the name matches the first element vs secondary elements?

Comment: Sure, you have `#list` and `#if` and all that. What have you tried, where do you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Inside your list, if found value, you can use [is_first](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_loop_var.html#ref_builtin_is_first)  Loop variable built-ins:

```
 <#if i?is_first>
   <#return "First">
 <#else>
   <#return "Secondary/Non Primary">
```